# testNG : how to find out if test execution is finished

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using testNG as a testing framework in my selenium automation project. I am executing test suites from testng.xml file. Now, I want to store test results after each test execution.
For that I have written a code that will zip my test-output folder to desired location.

Now, my question is - how to find out when my test execution will complete? or how would I know when to invoke my zip reports method?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using any build tools for running your tests??

Comment: yes, I am using maven for builds. But, my test execution is done by testNG and report is generated using ReportNG

Comment: @AfterSuite annotation is executed after your suite is executed, so you can use this method in your base class to let your program know that your test execution is finished

Comment: @rsakhale.. thanks, I think it should work. Definitely I will try it